# Set up a mock database in Python for unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unit-testing, ms-access, mocking

I want to set up a mock database (as opposed to creating a test database if possible) to check if the data is being properly queried and than being converted into a Pandas dataframe. I have some experience with mock and unit testing and have set-up previous test successfully. However, I'm having difficulty in applying how to mock real-life objects like databases for testing.

Currently, I'm having trouble generating a result when my test is run. I believe that I'm not mocking the database object correctly, I'm missing a step involved or my thought process is incorrect. I put my tests and my code to be tested in the same script to simplify things.

- I've thoroughly read thorough the Python unittest and mock documentation so I know what it does and how it works (For the most part).
- I've read countless posts on mocking in Stack and outside of it as well. They were helpful in understanding general concepts and what can be done in those specific circumstances outlined, but I could not get it to work in my situation.
- I've tried mocking various aspects of the function including the database connection, query and using the 'pd_read_sql(query, con)' function to no avail. I believe this is the closest I got.

## My Most Recent Code for Testing

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import unittest
import pandas.util.testing as tm

from unittest import mock

# Function that I want to test
def p2ctt_data_frame():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=My\Path\To\Actual\Database\Access Database.accdb;'
    )

    query = 'select * from P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs'

    # I want to make sure this dataframe object is created as intended
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn) 

    return df


class TestMockDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('directory1.script1.pyodbc.connect')  # Mocking connection
    def test_mock_database(self, mock_access_database):

        # The dataframe I expect as the output after query is run on the 'mock database'
        expected_result = pd.DataFrame({
            'POSTAL_CODE':[
                'A0A0A1'
            ],
            'DA_ID':[
                1001001
            ],
            'GHHDS_DA':[
                100
            ]
        })

        # This is the line that I believe is wrong. I want to create a return value that mocks an Access table
        mock_access_database.connect().return_value = [('POSTAL_CODE', 'DA_ID', 'GHHDS_DA'), ('A0A0A1', 1001001, 100)]

        result = p2ctt_data_frame()  # Run original function on the mock database

        tm.assert_frame_equal(result, expected_result) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I expect that the expected dataframe and the result after running the test using the mock database object is one and the same. This is not the case.

Currently, if I print out the result when trying to mock the database I get:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Furthermore, I get the following error after the test is run:

AssertionError: DataFrame are different;
DataFrame shape mismatch
[left]:  (0, 0)
[right]: (1, 3)

Comment: Why not query the database but only use the top 3 values? When testing for accuracy make sure the column names are correct and some other aspects of the data frame you are looking for like the postal code being 6 characters long.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! Would you say that, that's the best way to go about testing databases in general? I'm generally still iffy on unit tests versus integration tests and if they should be tested similarly.

Comment: What I’ve found is do both. This book taught me a lot about testing and how to do it correctly: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/praise.harry.html

Comment: Will take a read, thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would break it up into a few separate tests. A functional test that the desired result will be produced, a test to make sure you can access the database and get expected results, and the final unittest on how to implement it. I would write each test in that order completing the tests first before the actual function. If found that if I can't figure out how to do something I'll try it on a separate REPL or create a git branch to work on it then go back to the main branch. More information can be found here: https://obeythetestinggoat.com/book/praise.harry.html

Comments for each test and the reason behind it is in the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def p2ctt_data_frame(query='SELECT * FROM P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs;'): # set query as default
    with  pyodbc.connect(
        r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=My\Path\To\Actual\Database\Access Database.accdb;'
    ) as conn:  # use with so the connection is closed once completed

        df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    return df
```

Separate test file:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class TestMockDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_p2ctt_data_frame_functional_test(self):  # Functional test on data I know will not change
        actual_df = p2ctt_data_frame(query='SELECT * FROM P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs WHERE DA_ID = 1001001;')

        expected_df = pd.DataFrame({
            'POSTAL_CODE':[
                'A0A0A1'
            ],
            'DA_ID':[
                1001001
            ],
            'GHHDS_DA':[
                100
            ]
        })

        self.assertTrue(actual_df == expected_df)

    def test_access_database_returns_values(self):  # integration test with the database to make sure it works
        with pyodbc.connect(
            r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
            r'DBQ=My\Path\To\Actual\Database\Access Database.accdb;'
        ) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs WHERE DA_ID = 1001001;")
                result = cursor.fetchone()

        self.assertTrue(len(result) == 3)  # should be 3 columns by 1 row

        # Look for accuracy in the database
        info_from_db = []
        for data in result:  # add to the list all data in the database
            info_from_db.append(data)

        self.assertListEqual(   # All the information matches in the database
            ['A0A0A1', 1001001, 100], info_from_db
        )


    @mock.patch('directory1.script1.pd')  # testing pandas
    @mock.patch('directory1.script1.pyodbc.connect')  # Mocking connection so nothing sent to the outside
    def test_pandas_read_sql_called(self, mock_access_database, mock_pd):  # unittest for the implentation of the function
        p2ctt_data_frame()
        self.assert_True(mock_pd.called)  # Make sure that pandas has been called
        self.assertIn(
            mock.call('select * from P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs'), mock_pd.mock_calls
        )  # This is to make sure the proper value is sent to pandas. We don't need to unittest that pandas handles the
        # information correctly.
```

*I was not able to test this so there might be some bugs I need to fix

Comment: Wow thanks, that was super clear and useful! One question though. If test 1 passes, doesn't that mean that test 3 is unnecessary? The only reason I say this is because if the expected and actual data-frames are equal, doesn't that mean that Pandas had to be called with that specific query, therefore making testing the call to Pandas redundant?

Comment: In this case it is a bit redundant because we are looking at these functions in a vacuum. But let’s say you need the query to be validated because it’s using user input. We would want to create a separate `validate_query` in our `p2ctt_data_frame` function to handle it. When testing the `p2ctt_data_frame` I would mock `validate_query` in the unittest then make sure it is being called. Once that is done create a separate unittest, for `validate_query` to make sure it is doing what it is supposed to.