# Mock a database connection

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a db connector that has the connection in the constructor. I have been successful at mocking the connection, and the assert passes when checking against the two data types, but the assert fails due the values of "result" don't match the values of "mock_data". Mock data is returning a Mock Object (). I certain that the context manager inside the method get_data() is causing the issue, but I can't seem to get it to work. Would someone please help me out on how to get the values to match.

File *database_connector.py*

```
@dataclass
class DatabaseConnector:
    database_engine: str
    instance: str = "read"

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.database_engine = "".join(filter(str.isalnum, self.database_engine.lower()))
        self.instance = "".join(filter(str.isalnum, self.instance.lower()))
        self.connection = self.get_connection()

    def get_connection(self) -> Connection:
        kwargs = {
            "database": host,
            "host": host,
            "user": user,
            "password": password,
            "port": port
        }

        return pg8000.connect(**kwargs)
    
    def get_data(self, query: str) -> list[tuple]:
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        return data
```

File *mock_db.py*

```
db_path = "connectors.database.database_connector.DatabaseConnector"

class TestSPO(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("database_connector.DatabaseConnector.get_data")
    @patch("database_connector.DatabaseConnector.get_connection")
    def test_connection(self, mock_connection, mock_data):
        mock_record = (0, "1")
        mock_data.return_value = (0, "1")
        mock_connection.return_value = Mock()
        expected_result = InboundVolume().get_inbound_volume()
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, mock_record)
```

Comment: There are multiple posts on this topic on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576527/set-up-a-mock-database-in-python-for-unit-testing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931765/how-to-unit-test-a-method-that-contains-a-database-call-in-python), and many others. Have you tried them?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried many variations, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have updated the original code with a method2 based on another post I saw. Does the query need to be patched as well if using a context manager while returning data inside another function like how I have?

Comment: @PandasM Try to use `mock_connection.return_value = mock.MagicMock()` in your **Method1**.

Comment: The error I always get is AssertionError: 1 != 0

Comment: I was able to get it to pass, but I had to use a try and except around the database connection method called, get_data(). Is that correct, or should I of been able to mock the connection inside of get_data method without the need of a try and except? I returned an empty dict if an error was being thrown around due not having auth.

Comment: I have made edits to the code, as well as the question. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I added mock_record = (0, "1") before mock_data.return_value = (0, "1"), and it worked. Would someone please confirm that this is the correct way.